# How can I create UI to custom node

Tags: node.js, node-red

I want to create nodes like dashboard UI ([enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-dashboard))node buttons, form ,table etc...
custom node code have two input ,I want input render to website(HTML).
How can I do?
my node: http in -> custom node -> http out.
HTML:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        RED.nodes.registerType('lower-case', {
            category: 'input',
            color: '#a6bbcf',
            defaults: {name: {value:""},authtoken: {value:""} },
            credentials: { username: {type: "text"}, password: {type: "password"},},
            inputs: 1,
            outputs: 1,
            icon: "file.png",
            label: function() {return this.name || "lower-case'";},
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/html" data-template-name="lower-case">
        <div class="form-row">
            <label for="node-input-name"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="node-input-name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <label for="node-input-username"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="node-input-username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <label for="node-input-password"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="node-input-password">
        </div>
    </script>
```

JS:

```
module.exports = function(RED) {
        "use strict";
        function LowerCaseNode(config) {
            console.log("config", config)
            RED.nodes.createNode(this, config);
            var node = this;
            node.on('input', function(msg) {
                var username = this.credentials.username;
                var password = this.credentials.password;
                msg.payload = {
                    "username": username,
                    "password": password
                }
                node.send(msg);
            });
            this.close('close', function() {});
        }
        RED.nodes.registerType("lower-case", LowerCaseNode, {
            credentials: {
                username: { type: "text" },
                password: { type: "password" }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: First, please do not post images of code. Post the actual coffee as text and use the toolbar to format it. Images are hard to read and impossible to search or for people who need to use screen readers. Second, please  [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71655709/edit) the question to explain in more detail what you actually mean here. It really is not clear what you are asking, you need to add a lot more details

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send HTML back to the browser that is triggering your node via a pair of http-in/http-response nodes, then your node needs to set `msg.payload` to hold the HTML you want to send before it is sent to the http-response node.

You might also want to set the `msg.headers` to include a `content-type` entry for `text/html`